# OnMouseWheel not called in dialog-box

Tags: winapi, mfc

In have a dialog-box (`CDialog`).

All mouse events trigger their corresponding handlers, i.e.:

- Mouse-Left-Button-Down  events trigger the `OnLButtonDown` handler
- Mouse-Right-Button-Down events trigger the `OnRButtonDown` handler
- Mouse-Left-Button-Up    events trigger the `OnLButtonUp`   handler
- Mouse-Right-Button-Up   events trigger the `OnRButtonUp`   handler
- Mouse-Move              events trigger the `OnMouseMove`   handler

All, but Mouse-wheel events, which do not trigger the `OnMouseWheel` handler for some reason.

WOE??? (as in 'What On Earth', which is a mild way of expressing my thoughts on MFC at the moment).

Instead, I need to handle these events in the `PreTranslateMessage` handler.

Of course I can use this as a solution, but for coding reason I would highly prefer to handle them in the same manner that I handle all other mouse events.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Most of the answers that I've found suggest adding `ON_WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` to the message-map, but I'm already doing this of course (as I do for all other mouse events).

I found one answer suggesting to add `WS_TABSTOP` to the dialog-box style. Couldn't possibly see the logical sense in that, but tried it anyhow (without any success, as expected).

Thank you.

### MY CODE:

**Header File:**

```
class CInputDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CInputDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    virtual ~CInputDlg();

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT flags,CPoint point);
    afx_msg void OnMouseWheel(UINT flags,short delta,CPoint point);
};
```

**Source File:**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CInputDlg,CDialog)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_MOUSEHWHEEL()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CInputDlg::CInputDlg(CWnd* pParent):CDialog(IDD_DIALOG,pParent)
{
}

CInputDlg::~CInputDlg()
{
}

void CInputDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT flags,CPoint point)
{
    // This function is reached when I click the mouse-left-button
}

void CInputDlg::OnMouseWheel(UINT flags,short delta,CPoint point)
{
    // This function is not reached when I roll the mouse-wheel
}
```

**Resource File:**

```
IDD_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 400, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX |
WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: BTW: handling them in `PreTranslateMessage` sounds very fishy. The `WS_TABSTOP` suggestion sounds fishy too, where did you read this?

Comment: There is a bug in your code. That's all we can say without seeing your code or at least the relevant parts of it. And please tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve.(E.g.: _when the user turns the mouse wheel, I want the numbers in the edit control be incremented or decremented_). Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: In some forum called `codeguru`, which is where Google search leads me most of the time for WIN32 and MFC issues. Unfortunately (though perhaps for a good reason), there doesn't seem to be a sufficient amount of coverage for these topics on Stack Overflow. I'm guessing maybe this infrastructure is gradually becoming obsolete.

Comment: Which article exactly on codeguru? Yes MFC is somewhat obsolete, but there are still lots of old MFC applications being maintained.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: With regards to your second comment, I have added the relevant piece of code.

Comment: It should be `afx_msg BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT flags,short delta,CPoint point);` not `afx_msg void OnMouseWheel(UINT flags,short delta,CPoint point);`. This shouldn't even compile. Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I hope you understand now how important it is to show at least the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: It can be both according to what I see in file `afxmsg_.h` (and the empiric evidence for that is the fact that my code does in fact compile). To be honest, I did wonder about the two different versions of the `ON_WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` definition in that file, but I figured that MS knew what they were doing there and that both versions should work.

Comment: My I was wrong on the "I figured that MS knew what they were doing" part...

Comment: So which version of VS do you have? If I change BOOL to void it doesn't compile on my VS2015.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: VS2013. To be more precise, Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5, 2015 Microsoft Coorporation. So I guess you could call it VS-12, VS-2013 or VS-2015.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144946/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

The dialog message map:

```
...
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplicationDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL()   // <<< added this
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
```

The implementation:

```
BOOL CMFCApplicationDlg::OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
{
  // This feature requires Windows Vista or greater.
  // The symbol _WIN32_WINNT must be >= 0x0600.

  TRACE("Mouse wheel message: (%d, %d), d = %d\n", pt.x, pt.y, zDelta);
  return CDialog::OnMouseWheel(nFlags, zDelta, pt);
}
```

The the dialog class definition:

```
class CMFCApplicationDlg : public CDialog
{
  ...
  afx_msg BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt);  // added this
};
```

This is extracted from a freshly created dialog based MFC application. I just added the lines mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. The only difference between my current code and your suggestion is deriving the class from `CDialog` instead of `CDialogEx`. I will now give it a try.

Comment: OK, where exactly is class `CDialogEx` defined?

Comment: @goodvibration `CDialogEx` is automatically put by newer versions of  Visual Studio. Never mind, just replace `CDialogEx` by `CDialog`. I just edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well then, now there's no difference between your code and what I already have. Have you made sure that you can actually stop with a breakpoint at `OnMouseWheel` when you roll the wheel? If yes, then I guess that it might be related to the way that you initialize the `CDialog` itself. In other words, how exactly do you call the `CDialog` constructor from the `CMFCApplicationDlg` constructor? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure `OnMouseWheel` _is_ called because in Visual Studio's output window this is displayed everytime I move the mouse wheel: `atlTraceGeneral - Mouse wheel message: (1177, 837), d = 120`. I suggest you to make a new MFC dialog based application with the wizard and see how it's done.

Comment: _How exactly do you call the CDialog constructor from the CMFCApplicationDlg constructor?_ : there is nothing special done: `CMFCApplicationDlg dlg;
 m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
 INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();`

Comment: I meant with regards to `CMFCAppDlg::CMFCAppDlg(CWnd* pParent):CDialog(IDD_DIALOG,pParent)`. What is the definition of `IDD_DIALOG` in your resource file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144930/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 macros:

ON_WM_MOUSEHWHEEL() -> BOOL OnMouseWheel() and

ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL() -> void OnMouseHWheel().

You need use ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL().

Comment: It looks like you have your `OnMouseWheel()` and `OnMouseHWheel()` functions on the wrong macros (round the wrong way).